# implementation of link list in C without the input size

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

First, I define a structure to implement linked list:

```
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} Node;
```

Then, I have to insert an element into the linked list. And I cannot finish this part.

A example from my lecture notes tells me, when we insert an element, we should do something like that:

```
Node a, c; // originally
Node b; // insert-element
b->next = &c;
a->next = &b;
```

However, I have to declare a Node to implement it. But, here is my situation: I don't know the input size, maybe I have to insert 60 elements, or maybe I just have to insert 2 elements. What is the solution?

And another small, stupid problem, is there it any different between `a->next` and `a.next`?

Comment: You should read about pointers and about dynamic memory allocation (`malloc` and friends) first. `a->next` is the same as `(*a).next`.

Comment: [linked list tutorial](http://pastebin.com/HC1DLK4M)

Comment: please comment on posts you downvote, to let the OP know how the question can be improved

Comment: @sp2danny no, in many cases, that's not a good idea.  In some cases, it's a very bad idea indeed.

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can implement an empty linked-list:

```
typedef struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
} Node;

int main(){

  Node *a, *b;

  a=malloc(sizeof(Node));
  //here check if allocation has been done, if not error
  a->data=1;
  a->next=NULL;


  b=malloc(sizeof(Node));
  b->data=2;
  b->next=a;

  //and so on




  return 0;
}
```

in this way your linked-list will be like:
b ----> a -----> NULL
Now let's suppose you want to add 3 to the end of the linked-list; you can use this function:

```
void insertToEnd(Node *head, int newNumber)
{
   Node *newNode, *tmp;
   newNode=malloc(sizeof(Node));
   newNode->data=newNumber;
   newNode->next=NULL;

   tmp=head;

   if(head->next == NULL){
     head->next = newNode;
   }

   else
   {
   while(tmp->next != NULL)
    {
        if(tmp->next == NULL)
        {
            tmp->next = newNode;
        }
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
}


head=tmp;
}
```

I hope it works fine because i don't have c compiler right now. check it and let me know that if the function works fine

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: @unwind you mean b=malloc(sizeof(Node)); ?

Comment: You should probably click the link. :) But yes, or even better `b = malloc(sizeof *b);`.

Comment: @unwind thanks, Edited ;)

Comment: Then, if I want to insert an element at the end of the linked list. How can I implement it? beacuse I cannot do something like "node *c".

Comment: @zodiac now I will add to the post that function too.

Answer (score 2):

The sensible thing is to create a function that prepends a new list node to an existing list. We use `NULL` to mean "the empty list". We prepend since that saves having to step through the entire list every time.

```
Node * list_prepend(Node *head, int data)
{
  Node *n = malloc(sizeof *n);
  if(n != NULL)
  {
    n->next = head;
    n->data = data;
    return n;  /* The new head. */
  }
  return head;
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
int main(void)
{
  Node *list;

  list = list_prepend(NULL, 47);
  list = list_prepend(list, 11);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know how many Nodes you'll get, you'll have to allocate memory at runtime. `malloc()` and `free()` will do the job.

The difference between `a->next` and `a.next` is, well actually, `a`.
In the first construction the "a" is a pointer to a struct, in the second case "a" is a struct itself.